# How to express that "you dig your fingers into something soft and then pull a piece off it"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

How to express "**you dig your fingers into something soft (such as styrofoam or a loaf of bread) and then pull a piece off it**"?

For example, can we say "**I pawed / tore / ripped a piece off the bread**"?

Comment: You would say "I tore" if you want to use the 'tear' verb, and that is my suggestion. I tore a piece **off** (**from** is more formal)  the loaf.

Comment: Also [*partake*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/partake#etymonline_v_7251) in its oldest sense: "to take or have a part" (e.g. "I partook of the loaf").